# How to show my all image in image view in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView[] targetImage = new ImageView[5];
    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("Networking", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }

        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.d("NetworkingActivity", e1.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, Long> {
        //---takes in a list of image URLs in String type---
        protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
            long imagesCount = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                //---download the image---
                Bitmap imageDownloaded = DownloadImage(urls[i]);
                if (imageDownloaded != null ) {
                    //---increment the image count---
                    imagesCount++;
                    try {
                        //---insert a delay of 3 seconds---
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //---return the image downloaded---
                    publishProgress(imageDownloaded);
                }
            }

            //---return the total images downloaded count---
            return imagesCount;
        }

        //---display the image downloaded---
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... bitmap) {
            if(bitmap.length > 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < bitmap.length; i++) {
                    targetImage[i].setImageBitmap(bitmap[i]);
                }
            }
            // tIV[values[i]].setImageBitmap(tBM[values[i]]);
        }

        //---when all the images have been downloaded---
        protected void onPostExecute(Long imagesDownloaded) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Total"  + imagesDownloaded + " images downloaded" ,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        targetImage[0] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.target0);
        targetImage[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.target1);
        targetImage[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.target2);

        new DownloadImageTask().execute(
            "http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/sobin.jpg" ,
            "http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/shamol.jpg",
            "http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/rifat.jpg"
        );

        ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        flipper.startFlipping();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Import picasso library in your project:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

And try this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            ImageView[] targetImage = new ImageView[5];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    targetImage[0] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.target0);
                    targetImage[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.target1);
                    targetImage[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.target2);  
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/sobin.jpg").into(targetImage[0]);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/shamol.jpg").into(targetImage[1]);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/rifat.jpg").into(targetImage[2]);
    }
    }
```